# Setup Transport agent for Internal Mails in Exchange Server 2013

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to setup Transport Agent for Internal mails in Exchange Server 2013.
i read MSDN links for transport Agent .
[Create transport agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204097%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx#bk_prerequisites)

In this link it provides information only for SMTP Mails.
I need to create Transport Agent for Internal Mails i,e. with in my Exchange server MailBox users mails , no need of external mails [SMTP] .

Actually i am creating **Transport Agent for getting Mail headers of all received mails of my Server.**
How can i create transport agent for only Internal received mails.

please share your ideas. This is the first time i am working on Exchange Server Development.

Answer (score 1):

To handle all mails passing through your mail server (internal and external), you Should implement a **RoutingAgent** rather than SmtpReceiveAgent:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563310(v=exchg.150).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563310%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

You can then hook to the **OnSubmittedMessage** event and inspect every message. The first thing to do in your event handler would be to inspect the sender/recipients of the message, and issue a **return;** statement if the message is not interesting (IE an external correspondence, an NDR etc.) - this will cause the message to be sent "as is" without processing.